The first reference which formulated k-means problem as MIQCP using big-M constraint
k-means, or MSS (minimum-sum-of-squares) clustering is a basic problem in statistics. To remind, for a set of points $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_N$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, the problem is to find $K$ centres $Q_1, Q_2, \dots, Q_K$ (in $\mathbb{R}^d$) and assign the points to the centres with indicator-variables $\left\{x_{nk}, \, n=1, \dots,N, \,k=1,\dots,K\right\}$, so that this problem is minimized:
$$\min\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^K x_{nk}\left\| P_n-Q_k\right\|^2_2 \\
\text{s.t. } \sum_{k=1}^K x_{nk} = 1, \; n=1, \dots, N \\
x_{nk} \in \left\{0, 1\right\}, \; Q_k \in \mathbb{R}^d
$$
k-means problem can be reformulated the following way:
$$
\min\sum_{n=1}^N d_n \\
\text{s.t. } \\
\left\|P_1-Q_k\right\|_2^2 \leq d_1  + (1-x_{1k})M, \quad k=1,\dots,K, \\
\left\|P_2-Q_k\right\|_2^2 \leq d_2  + (1-x_{2k})M, \quad k=1,\dots,K,\\
\dots \\
\left\|P_N-Q_k\right\|_2^2 \leq d_N  + (1-x_{Nk})M, \quad k=1,\dots,K
$$
Here $M$ is a sufficiently large constant. In the thesis I have read, this is called ``the big-M technique''.
The above problem is a MIQCP (mixed-integer-quadratically-constrained-programming) problem and could be approached with, for example, gurobi.
I wonder who should be addressed (as a reference) to be the first one who has come up with such problem formulation.

From your question, I can't tell if you're asking about the origin of big-M constraints or the origin of k-means via MIP. I'm going to assume that you mean the latter, and it's a deep hole. The paper that you referenced is not nearly sufficient. Here is some more to read to get history and context on this topic:

"APPROXIMATING K-MEANS-TYPE CLUSTERING VIA SEMIDEFINITE PROGRAMMING" by Peng and Wei.
"The ratio-cut polytope and K-means clustering" by Rosa and Khajavirad. And they have a follow-up paper on that.


thank you for the reply. I was actually interested about the origins of big-M MIQCP formulation. I know that it is possible to formulate k-means problems alternatively, e.g., using the work by Peng and Wei, which I am actually familiar with, but I am particularly interested in MIQCP formulation as presented in the question, because Peng's approach cannot be applied in my situation. The second reference I have not studied, I will take a look, thank you. I agree that the thesis I have referenced is very basic one, but it is a good start in my opinion to get an overview of the formulation.
